# Echoing php variables with html

Tags: php, html, web

I have the following code, but keep running into a syntax error on line 7, saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'htmlentities' (T_STRING)." Is this not the correct way to echo php and html at the same time? Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, department, website filename FROM Profile");
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  echo('<div class="col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-rounded" src="'.$row['filename'].'"/>
    <p class="caption">');
  echo('<a href="'htmlentities($row['website'])'">'.($row['first_name']).' '.htmlentities($row['last_name']).'</a>')
  echo(', '.htmlentities($row['department']));
  echo('</p> </div>');
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo('<a href="' . htmlentities.....` missed a `.` and a `;` at the end of that line. I would suggest you get a editor with at-least basic syntax highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo should be without parenthesis and you're missing . on a few of your echo commmands.

Answer (score 0):

To join an echo string (concatenate) you need to add the strings with a "."

Please use :

```
<?php

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, department, website filename FROM Profile");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<div class="col-sm-3">
   <img class="img-rounded" src="' . $row['filename'] . '"/>
   <p class="caption">';
   echo '<a href="' . htmlentities($row['website']) . '">' . ($row['first_name']) . ' ' . htmlentities($row['last_name']) . '</a>';
   echo ', ' . htmlentities($row['department']);
   echo '</p> </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you use a editor that will give you debugging information. 

Something like NetBeans. I use NetBeans all the time as my preferred PHP editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate your strings when you interrupt the string like

```
echo('<a href="' . htmlentities($row['website']) . '">'.($row['first_name']).' '
```

At the htmlentities part you are missing the dots for stringconcatenation

Answer (score 0):

You have concatenated the string in wrong way. Try following

```
<?php
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, department, website, filename 
                    FROM Profile");
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
    {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3">
                <img class="img-rounded" src="'.$row['filename'].'"/>
                <p class="caption">';
        echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($row['website']).'">'.$row['first_name'].' '.htmlentities($row['last_name']).'</a>';
        echo ', '.htmlentities($row['department']);
        echo '</p> </div>';
    }
?>
```

**OR**

You can also try the following as an alternative way..

```
<?php
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, department, website, filename 
                    FROM Profile");
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
    {
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo $row['filename'] ?>"/>
            <p class="caption">
                <a href="<?php echo htmlentities($row['website']) ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'] ?> 
                </a>
                <?php echo ', '.htmlentities($row['department']); ?>
            </p> 
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit the code you try it. You miss . and ;

```html
echo '<div class="col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-rounded" src="'.$row['filename'].'"/>
       <p class="caption">';
  echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($row['website']).'">'.($row['first_name']).' '.htmlentities($row['last_name']).'</a>';
  echo ', '.htmlentities($row['department']);
  echo '</p> </div>';
```